# Adding an entity to the context

Tags: entity-framework

Why is this simple add not working! I get a previous record from the database, instantiate a new entity to add by using the previous record's data, except I increment the report number by 1. I keep getting the error "The property 'ReportNbr' is part of the primary key and cannot be modified." I thought this error was when you tried to update an existing entities' primary key field.

Here's my object and previous record that I use.

```
var previousRecord = _repo.GetLatestRecord();
            var recordToAdd = new Record()
            {
                Year = previousRecord.Year,
                Month = previousRecord.Month,
                ReportNbr = ++previousRecord.ReportNbr,
                ...//other info
            };
_repo.AddRecord(recordToAdd);
```

The three fields show are the primary key to the table. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: if _repo is your context, wouldn't it be _repo.Records.add(recordToAdd)?

Comment: I have a generic add method I use for my entire repository, so inside AddRecord there is a call to the generic method. I have also tried _context.Records.Add(recordToAdd) inside the repository and I get the same error.

Comment: Well if you have change tracking on, the ++previousRecord.ReportNbr is updating the previousRecord.  Try doing ReportNbr = previousRecord.ReportNbr + 1;

Comment: That was the problem...so simple. Thanks man, didn't know that incrementing like that caused change tracking to happen.

Comment: I'll add it as an answer so you can accept it and close it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have change tracking on, the

```
++previousRecord.ReportNbr
```

is updating the previousRecord.

Try

```
ReportNbr = previousRecord.ReportNbr + 1;
```